# Не работает событие onSubmit. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form

Есть компонент формы с кнопкой:

```
export class Form extends Component {
  changeDateTextHandler = ({ target }) => {
    const { changeDateText } = this.props;
    changeDateText(target.value);
  }

  changeMoneyTextHandler = ({ target }) => {
    const { changeMoneyText } = this.props;

    if (target.value === '') {
      changeMoneyText('');
    }

    if (!+target.value) {
      return;
    }

    changeMoneyText(+target.value);
  }

  formHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Hi');
  }

  addItemHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { addItem, currentInputData, clearInputFields } = this.props;
    addItem({
      id: uniqueId(),
      category: {
        categoryName: 'Start value',
        categorySign: '',
      },
      date: currentInputData.dateText,
      money: +currentInputData.moneyText,
    });
    clearInputFields();
  }

  render() {
    const { list, currentInputData } = this.props;

    const renderStartButton = () => (
      (list.length || !(currentInputData.dateText && currentInputData.moneyText)) ? (
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-add_disabled">Add start value</button>
      ) : (
        <button type="button" onClick={this.addItemHandler} className="btn btn-add">Add start value</button>
      )
    );

    return (
      <div className="form-moneyCalc d-flex justify-content-md-between pt-2">
        <form onSubmit={this.formHandler}>
          <div className="row justify-content-md-between justify-content-sm-center">
              <div className="col">
                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Date" value={currentInputData.dateText} onChange={this.changeDateTextHandler} />
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Money" value={currentInputData.moneyText} onChange={this.changeMoneyTextHandler} />
              </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        {renderStartButton()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Хочу повесить на кнопку и на форму схожие обработчики, чтобы при нажатие на enter/кнопку происходило одно и тоже действие. Но не могу понять, почему не работает событие onSubmit на форме.

Comment: Помоему если бы кнопка была в теге `form`, то оно бы сабмитило.

Comment: Не, так тоже не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Добавить `{renderStartButton()}` в форму
2. `<button type="submit"`